# ghost dosen't work in subdomain

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-12.04, ghost-blog

i have VPS server work in digitalocean with nginx and ubuntu 12.4 LTS 64bit, i try to make ghost blog work in my subdomain blog.csbukhari.com but it dose not work.

this is my conf file in nginx

```
server {  
   listen 80;
    server_name blog.csbukhari.com;

    location / {
            expires 8d;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_read_timeout 5m;
            proxy_connect_timeout 5m;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2368;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
}
```

and i add the subdomain blog in dns as A record

Comment: What error message are you getting? The config looks quite correct, maybe you can mention the important bits from the config.js file in Ghost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see my example conf file [here](http://www.howtoinstallghost.com/how-to-host-ghost-on-a-nginx-subdomain/) but yours looks right.

I assume you have restarted nginx and you have Ghost started and listing on port 2368?

Comment: i try it before i write my problem hear it's not work with my, yes sure i restart nginx..